# How to create a python result array from a for loop?

Tags: python

I want to create a results array from the results of a for loop for example say i ran my for loop with results 3,3,5,6,7,8,9,1,5 and i want my array to go up to 10 id want to create an array that looks like
[0, 0
1,1
2,0
3,2
4,0
5,2
6,1
7,1
8,1
9,1
10,0]

any help is appreciated very beginner programmer

Comment: What _exactly_ is the correlation between the first result and the second?

Comment: Stack messed up the array it should be array with 2 column first column 0-10 and the second column how many times that number appears

Comment: the resuls array should look like

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `dict` instead of a array. The code is as follow:

```
sample=[3,3,5,6,7,8,9,1,5]
def count_occurrence(sample):
    occurrence={}
    for i in range(10):
        occurrence[i]=0
    for num in sample:
        occurrence[num]+=1
    return occurrence
o=count_occurrence(sample)
print(o)
#if you still want the array you mentioned:
a=sorted(list(o.items()))
print(a)
```